# Is there a way to detect if ICU is installed on debian based systems?

Tags: debian, software-installation

I want to know if http://site.icu-project.org/ is installed on my debian based machine, is there a way to know that it is installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact answer depends on what you’re looking for:

- if you only need the runtime library, check for the presence of a `libicu` package (`libicu63` on Debian 10), or the existence of `/usr/lib/*/libicui18n.so.*`;
- if you need the development files (which give access to the runtime library when building), check for the presence of the `libicu-dev` package, or the existence of `/usr/lib/*/libicui18n.so`, or with `pkg-config`, the availability of the `icu-i18n` package (`pkg-config icu-i18n` should succeed);
- if you need the development tools, check for the presence of the `icu-devtools` package, or the existence of `icuinfo` on the `PATH` (`command -v icuinfo` should succeed).